# How do I update an android sqlite database column value to null using ContentValues?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

For example, I want to do the following on a database update.

Is there a constant I can use instead of `null`, which won't compile if I use it like:

```java
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(KEY_RISK_AMOUNT, null); // what constant do I use instead of null?
```

Comment: I found the answer...I need to do this: args.putNull(KEY_RISK_AMOUNT)

Comment: You should answer your own question and come back tomorrow to mark it as the accepted answer if it works as intended.

Comment: I don't think I can answer my own question, at least I don't see how...

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Use [`ContentValues.putNull(java.lang.String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#putNull%28java.lang.String%29):

```java
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.putNull(KEY_RISK_AMOUNT);
```

Comment: bonus points for answering this question when the o.p. already answered himself in the comments 20 days before your answer and then getting 10 upvotes! Nicely done :)

Comment: Well, someone _had_ to do it. :p

Comment: good answer... putNull easy to understand this method on content values class :)